# Questions on piecewise hereditary algebras

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite dimensional quiver algebra over a field $k$ that is quasi-tilted and representation-finite (this implies that $A$ is a tilted algebra). Assume that the Coxeter polynomial of $A$ is equal to the Coxeter polynomial to an algebra of the form $kQ$.

> Question 1: Is it true that $A$ is derived equivalent to $kQ$?

I think the answer is yes and I search a reference for this, at least when $Q$ is of Dynkin type.

> Question 2: Assume $A$ is piecewise hereditary of Dynkin type $Q$. What is the smallest/maximal number of indecomposables representations $A$ can have?

For example there is a piecewise hereditary algebra $A$ of type $E_8$ with 62 indecomposables. I wonder whether this is the lowest number for type $E_8$. I would think that the maximal number is attained in the hereditary case and is equal to half of the number of roots of the Dynkin type.